# Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is not homotopic to $X=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have the following two subsets of Real Numbers.

$X=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$

$Y=\mathbb{N}$

I want to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is not homotopic to $X=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$.

**EDITS**

We say two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopic if there are continuous maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $Id_{Y}$ and $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $Id_{X}$

I am reading from Hatcher's book.

Comment: What is your definition of "homotopic" in this situation?

Comment: @Arthur Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: A word on notation: it is customary to say that two maps are homotopic, and two spaces as in the definition you give are *homotopy equivalent*. This is in line with Hatcher's usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: If a function $h:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ is a function which is homotopic to the identity, what can you say about $h$? For instance, what could $h(1)$ possibly be?

Hint 2: What do you know about the image of continuous maps where the domain is compact?

Comment: For second Hint:  Since any open set containing $0$ contain all but finitely many points of $X$. Every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Therefore $X$ is compact and image of a compact set under continuous map is compact.

Comment: @Tensor_Product Exactly. Therefore, the image of $f\circ g$ (which is no larger than the image of $g$) must be compact. If you now use hint 1, can $f\circ g$ possibly be homotopic to the identity on  $\Bbb N$?

Comment: I know $\mathbb{N}$ is not compact. I am not able to follow hint 1.

Comment: If there is a homotopy $H:\Bbb N\times [0,1]\to \Bbb N$ between $h$ and $\operatorname{Id}_{\Bbb N}$, then for any fixed $n\in \Bbb N$, the function $H_n = H(n, -)$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb N$, where $H_n( 0) = h(n)$ and $H_n(1) = n$. What could $h(n)$ possibly be?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong:   Now $H_n$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ which is a compact set to $\mathbb{N}$. So $H_n([0,1])$ should be compact. so the only choice we have is finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Tensor_Product That's correct, but it's even worse than that: for a given natural number $m$, the set $\{m\}\in \Bbb  N$ is both open and closed, so $H_n^{-1}(\{m\})$ is both open and closed in $[0,1]$. What are the possibilities?

Comment: Since $[0,1]$ is connected the only set which is both open and closed is $[0,1]$ and $\phi$. Now Inverse image of open(closed) set is open(closed). So either it is whole of $[0,1]$ or empty set.

Comment: That's right. So $H_n^{-1}(\{m\})$ is either $[0,1]$ or three empty set, which means that $H_n$ is constant, which again means that $h=Id_{\Bbb N}$. So only the identity function is homotypic to the identity function. Together with your conclusion from hint 2, $f\circ g$ cannot be homotypic to the identity, so $X$ and $Y$ are not homotypic.

Comment: I have a doubt: $H_n$ is a cont. function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{N}$. We have shown that it is constant, i.e  $H_n(x)=m$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ where $m$ is a fixed natural number. But how does it imply that h is identity ?

Comment: @Tensor_Product Because $H$ is a homotopy between $h$ and the identity, which means by definition of homotopy that $H(n, 0) =H_n(0) =  h(n)$ while $H(n, 1) = H_n(1)= n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time.